# ADA Color Contrast - Best Practices

Tags: website-design, sketch-app, interface-design

We're currently working on a new website and ran some tests to check ADA compliance on our website.

There's a color we're using that isn't compliant on certain font sizes.

We also use this color on map pins and letters ("A", "B", "C") on a list that corresponds with the map.

The development team we're going with said those are treated as visual elements, rather than text and pass the contrast checker.

However, we know that this color doesn't pass as text for contrast.

Is it safer to trust the machine that runs the test, understanding letters are treated as visual elements but if they were set as just normal text, it wouldn't pass? OR, do we just find a new color altogether?

Comment: Though not exactly the same question, the answer provided to this previous question may be of help: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119108/distinguishing-information-via-colors/119127#119127

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinguishing information via colors](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119108/distinguishing-information-via-colors)